# Изменение цвета фона при определенном условии

Tags: unity3d

Я нубас-ньюфаг. Делаю гиперказуалку, там есть текущие очки и игровой рекорд, в скрипте это соответственно ochki и record.
Хочу сделать чтобы когда рекорд изменяется менялся рандомно цвет фона один раз. Ну то есть прибавился рекорд на одно очко цвет фона изменился один раз, прибавился рекорд ещё на одно очко цвет фона изменился ещё один раз и так далее.
Погуглил, кое-что нашел и написал в методе Update()

```
if (ochki >= record) camera.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f);
```

Можно сказать работает но не так как надо, после прибавления рекорда на одно очко начинает цвет фона меняться за секунду несколько раз. Как я сам понимаю наверное это из-за метода Update. И так продолжается быстрое рандомное изменение цвета до того момента когда текущие очки минуснутся и станут снова ниже рекорда. С одной стороны вроде бы прикольно, но мне бы хотелось все-таки сделать как я описал вначале, чтобы изменение цвета только один раз на каждое новое очко в рекорде.
И ещё второй вариант хотелось бы попробовать, чтобы цвет фона менялся рандомно один раз при прибавлении каждых 10 текущих очков, тут я тоже не понимаю как написать формулу, типа if......... то есть как выразить такое условие при помощи знаков < > = и подобных им.
Помогите пожалуйста, вот на всякий случай то что сейчас у меня написано в Update. И верно я понимаю что надо писать в другом методе?

```
public void Update()
    {
        if (ochki >= record) record = ochki;
        RecordText.text = record.ToString();
        OchkiText.text = ochki.ToString();

        PlayerPrefs.SetFloat("My", record);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();


        if (ochki >= record) camera.GetComponent<Camera>().backgroundColor = new Color(Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), Random.Range(0f, 1f), 1f);

    }
```

Comment: Так... Непонятно, что вам непонятно. Насколько я понял ваша задача: "менять background на каждое очко, если очков больше, чем рекорд". В чем проблема менять background каждый раз, когда очко добавляется, при условии, что очков больше, чем рекорд? У вас же есть функция добавления очков? Update тут вообще (скорее всего) не нужен, так как очки игрок получает не каждый кадр.

Answer (score 0):

Вы правы, делать такое в Update нельзя, т.к. будут возникать проблемы, подобные вашей. Лучше в данном случае использовать события. Вынесите код, который отвечает за счет в отдельный класс.

Что - то вроде этого:

```
using System;

public class Score
{
    public event Action ScoreChanged; // Определяем событие 

    private int _score = 0;

    public void IncreaseScore(int amount) // Увеличить счет на определенное число amount
    {
        _score += amount;
        ScoreChanged?.Invoke(); // вызываем событие, когда счет изменится
    }
}
```

Здесь вы определяете событие и, когда счет изменится, все подписчики этого события вызовут определенный метод.

Далее показываю как подписываться на событие:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class SomeClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Score _score; //счет

    private void Start()
    {
        _score.ScoreChanged += DoStuff; // Подписка на событие, когда произойдет ScoreChanged?.Invoke(), вызовется метод DoStuff()
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _score.ScoreChanged -= DoStuff; // Отписка от события, чтобы не вылезали ошибки, если объект SomeClass будет удален со сцены
    }

    private void DoStuff()
    {
        Debug.Log("1234");
    }
}
```

Теперь, когда у вас изменяется счет, вызывается метод `DoStuff`, который пишет в консоль - 1234.
Здесь вы подписываете метод `DoStuff(`) на событие `ScoreChanged` при помощи оператора `+=`. Важно, чтобы сигнатуры метода и делегата события совпадали, в данном случае это означает, что `DoStuff` не имеет аргументов и тип события `ScoreChanged` является Action, а не Action.

Если понадобится выполнять какие-либо операции со счетом, то можно изменить тип события с `Action` на `Action<int>` и, соответственно, метод `DoStuff()` на `DoStuff(int count)`

Также, подписываться можно в `OnEnable()`, а отписываться, соответственно, в `OnDisable()`. Главное никогда не забывать отписываться от события, иначе это может быть чревато ошибками, которые будет сложно найти.

Каким образом будете менять цвет фона, решайте сами, т.к. способов огромное количество. Делать изменение фона нужно в методе `DoStuff()`.

Больше про события можно почитать на сайтах, типа metanit и др.